# Como capturar las pulsaciones de un teclado en termux?

Tags: c++

Necesito hacer un pequeño programa para termux con C++17 y clang++, pero no quiero utilizar cin o similar, lo que quiero es que capture las pulsaciones y no muestre la letra o que escribe, no sé que modulo utilizar.

Comment: Esto que pides es muy poco habitual. La lectura de datos en C++ se hace mediante búfer de datos el cuál inevitablemente pasa por `std::cin`, si quieres saltarte ese paso deberías acceder directamente a los búferes de sistema o a aún más bajo nivel. Necesitaremos más detalles: ¿Es una aplicación de consola? ¿Una aplicación en segundo plano?

Comment: En cualquier sistema POSIX [termios](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) debería resultar de ayuda para lo que buscas.. No he probado con C++ pero el siguiente código en Python lo probé en TERMUX por curiosidad cuando publiqué la pregunta y funciona perfectamente y en esencia hace lo que buscas, capturar el carácter  y no mostrarlo (modo canónico desactivado).

Answer (score 0):

Probé este código en mí termux, funciono correctamente, muchas gracias PaperBirdMaster y FJSevilla

Este codigo lo encontre en:
https://baulderasec.wordpress.com/programacion/programacion-con-linux/5-terminales/detectar-pulsaciones-de-las-teclas/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
static int peek_character = -1;

void init_keyboard();
void close_keyboard();

int kbhit();
int readch();

init main() {
  int ch = 0;

  init_keyboard();

  while(ch != 'q') {
    sleep(0);

    if (kbhit()) {
      ch = readch();
      printf("tecla: %c\n", ch);
    }
  }

  close_keyboard();

  return 0;
}

void init_keyboard() {
  tcgetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);

  new_setttings = initial_settings;
  new_setttings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  new_setttings.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
  new_setttings.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
  new_setttings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  new_setttings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
}

void close_keyboard() {
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);
}

int kbhit() {
  char ch;
  int nread;

  if (peek_character != -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
  nread = read(0, &ch, 1);
  new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);

  if (nread == 1) {
    peek_character = ch;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int readch() {
  char ch;

  if (peek_character != 1) {
    ch = peek_character;
    peek_character = -1;
    return ch;
  }

  read(0, &ch, 1);
  return ch;
}
```